# "cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)" in the generated source from generated endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, android-studio-2.3

For an unknown reason, when I tried to build my Google App Engine endpoints, I get these errors in all of the API java files generated by Android Studio:

**Error:(400, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(402, 29) error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)**

I did some initial troubleshooting and found out that there's a Builder class inside the java file and it extends **AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder**.  I looked at the source for the Builder class and I cannot find the method.

Why all of the sudden am I getting these errors?  Help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Same thing happened to me this morning.

I resolved it by adding this in my backend project

```
appengine {
    endpoints {
        googleClientVersion = '1.23.0'
    }
}
```

and updating this version in my app gradle file.

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0')
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck getting the "implementation" to work (on 2.3.3), so compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0' works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep that's correct. You will need to be to be using V3 for the implementation keyword. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Same compiling crash. Adding googleClientVersion = '1.23.0' resolved the issue ; why such changes have been pushed in force by Google team?

Comment: Hi, do you have a tips for this related consequential issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585118/android-studio-cannot-deploy-backend-execution-failed-for-task-apptransform

Comment: @RafiqAhmad, i upgraded to V2 and indeed this solution was not satisfactory. I implemented some changes listed in the warnings during build and now it is ok. Check the above link to my question on SO if it can help

Comment: @mg3 Just update these dependencies                                             compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android', version: '1.23.0' problem is solved.Previously it was 1.22.0

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same problem. I upgraded google client libs to 1.23.0 and it worked (earlier was 1.22.0)

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, AAP...I gave the rating to JamieH, because the googleClientVersion is also needed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

We already had these in our backend build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
}
```

All we needed was adding:

```
appengine {
    endpoints {
        googleClientVersion = '1.23.0'
    }
}
```

But it'd have been nice if Google didn't break our codes every once in awhile out of the blue and wasting hours of development time!

Comment: Happy to see i am not the only frustrated guy by the situation...but i am still investigating as above solution doesnt work with Endpoints Frameworks V2 in backend