# Android Studio cannot deploy backend : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug

Tags: java, android-studio, google-app-engine

when trying to deploy my appengine backend , I got suddenly this week the issue (“cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)”) similar to  following SO question : ["cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)" in the generated source from generated endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554771/cannot-find-symbol-method-setbatchpathstring-in-the-generated-source-from-ge)

I resolved it by adding (still wondering why this sudden need of change):

```
appengine {
endpoints {
    googleClientVersion = '1.23.0'
  }
}
```

However this conducted to a second deployment issue  with log :

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
>   Blockquote

I precise that i can build my app. Error is happening when trying to deploy GAE backend.
There was many SO answers related to similar exceptio for android client but none of them worked.

Help please

Here is my log :

```
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

>* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted

>* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

>* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:453)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:180)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:158)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1345)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:279)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:178)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:631)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:376)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:290)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:174)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:623)
    ... 4 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 35.807 secs
```

Comment: Restarted PC, AS...
Invalidate Caches and Restart doesnt solve...
Latest version of AS 2.3.3 doesnt solve...

Comment: I migrated to Endpoints Frameworks V2 but this put me back to the first issue for backend when  buiding : Cannot find  method setBatchPath(String)

Comment: App and backend can build successfully in command but the apk is not generated in the build folder...i dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Changes solved my 2nd deployment issue and enabled the build and deployment of APK. One of my module was still having compiling with Java 1.5 in Gradle, which i corrected with Java 1.7. And another module was having duplicating path on the system. When corrected,failure disappeared.